# Determine whether the functional sequences are pointwise convergent, in the case of convergence, determine whether uniformly so.

Tags: real-analysis

The functional sequence:

$(e^{-nx^2})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ $(x\in \mathbb{R})$

When $x\in\mathbb{R} \not{0}$ $\>\>\>\>$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-nx^2}$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/e^{n} = 0$

When $x=0 $ $\>\>\>\>$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-nx^2}$ = $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{0} = 1$

So the functional sequence is pointwise convergent to the limit function:

$f(x) =  1 \>\>\>\>if\>\>\>\> x=0$

$f(x) =  0 \>\>\>\>otherwise$

What is the next step to establish uniform convergence or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem which states that if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions which converge uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ must be continuous.

Can you apply this theorem to your problem?

Comment: Am I right in saying that $f$ isn't continuous, while $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions and therefore it does not converge uniformly? But if $f$ was continuous then it would converge uniformly?

Comment: For your first question, yes you are correct. The contrapositive of "$f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ implies $f$ is continuous" is "If $f$ is not continuous, then $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$". The contrapositive of a statement is equivalent to the statement.

Comment: For your second question, the converse of $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ implies $f$ is continuous" is "$f$ is continuous implies $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$". However, the converse of a statement is not always equivalent to the statement. In this case, the converse is false. Consider $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) = (n+1)x^n(1-x)$. Then, $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$, but $f_n(\tfrac{n}{n+1}) = (1-\tfrac{1}{n+1})^n \to 1/e$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, there is no $N$ s.t. $|f_n(x)| < 1/4$ for all $n \ge N$ and all $x \in [0,1]$. So $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: This is great, thank you for the help!